# how to fill array list between 2 points?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

i have this piece of code. 
 To explain:

The user inputs "initcores" data and "ttime" data (the "fcores" is a 
 result).

I want to fill the x array with values from 0 to ttime  and the y from 
 initcores to fcores and do the scatter plot ,x vs y.

I have one problem :

> > If i put " for (double  t=0;t<=fcores;t=t+fcores/10.0){ 
> >                            y.add(t);   "
> >
> > it gives me a plot but its wrong.
> >
> > if i put " for (double  t=initcores ;t<=fcores;..."  (which is 
> >      right because we are starting from initcores)
> >
> > it doesn't appear anything in the plot.

Am i not doing sth right here?

Thank you!

```
 ......... 
         Double initcores= getInitcores(); 
         Double fcores= getFcores(); 
         Double ttime=getTime(); 

         ArrayList<Double> x =new ArrayList<Double>(); 
         ArrayList<Double> y =new ArrayList<Double>(); 

         //fill x,y values 
          for (double t=0;t<=ttime;t+=ttime/10.0){ 
                  x.add(t);
          } 
          for (double  t=initcores;t<=fcores;t+=fcores/10.0){ 
                  y.add(t); 
          } 

TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Number of cores"); 
                 for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++){ 
                         for (int j=0;j<y.size();j++){ 

                        series.add(i,j); 
                         } 
                 } 
     ..........
```

--------------EDIT --------------------------------------

If i use :

```
double [] x = {0.0,ttime};           //time axis
double [] y = {initcores,fcores};  //number of cores axis

TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Number of cores");
        for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            series.add(x[i],y[i]);
        }
```

it gives me a plot with only 2 points.That's why i am trying to fill the points between them (for x axis :0-ttime ,for y axis:initcores-fcores).

Comment: what is wrong? what you are expecting and what you got?

Comment: As i say i am expecting a lot of points ,for example from 0 - ttime.I The user gives only ttime,initcores.The result is fcores.I am trying to fill the points between 0-ttime an initcores-fcores.But i get an empty plot.If instead of " for (double  t=initcores;t<=fcores.." put "for (double=0..)" ,then i get a plot but it's totally wrong.

Comment: I liked your question, but could you reformulate it? It is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Pih:I am sorry ,i can't  think another way to express it.The user enters ttim e (so for x axis i want to create 0-ttime values) and initcores (so fro y axis i want to create initcores-fcoress values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your `for`-loops wrong. Use the following ones and you should be fine:

```
 for (int i=0;i<=10;i++){ 
     x.add(ttime / 10.0 * i);
 } 

 for (int i=0;i<=10;i++){ 
     y.add(initcores + ((fcores - initcores) / 10 * i)); 
 }
```

These loops will give you 11 points, but you can adjust them to your needs.

**Update**

You naturally have to use the correct values from the list. Make sure that both lists have same length.

```
ArrayList<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
ArrayList<Double> y = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

... above code ...

TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Number of cores");
for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
    series.add(x.get(i),y.get(i));
}
```

Comment: :The way you have it it fills points between 0-10.I want to fill points between 0-ttime and initcores-fcores.

Comment: Did you check it out? For the first loop you will get: 0, (1/10)*ttime, (2/10)*ttime, ..., (9/10)*ttime, ttime. Similarly for the second one, but starting with initcores up to fcores with 9 equidistant points in between.

Comment: :Yes,i checked.For every input i put,it always gives me a plot with x-values from 0-10 and y-values from 0-10.But i want the values to be from 0-ttime and initcores-fcores.(so the plot is wrong)

Comment: I guess you're filling your TimeSeries wrong. See update in answer.

Comment: :Yes ,you were right!Now it runs ok.But the problem is that i was expecting a curve line(exponential decay).Instead,i am taking straight line.I can't understand.(since you answered my question i accept it and voted,but if you could tell me what to do with this now?).Thanks!

Comment: The curve depends on the points you are adding to your series. In the above loops I've just chosen the same distance (1/10) between points for both x and y lists. It's up to you to provide the proper data. You will have to fill the y-List with actual values, not interpolated ones, if you know how it should look like. You just provided the start and end point, and all values in between have been calculated according to the function in the for-loop. You are free to change that.

Comment: :So,i must fill the y array with real values.That is,'fcores' (which is the result i am taking)  for every 'ttime'.Sth like"   ArrayList<Double> data =new ArrayList<Double>();"       and then                                               "for (int i=0;i<=ttime;i++){
          data.add(fcores); 
         }"   and then fill y with that?If its not hard to tell me ,i'll appreciate.If its hard leave it,its ok.Thanks!

Comment: :Hello, i created another post in case you are interested.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019356/how-to-fill-array-between-two-points-with-data-from-another-activity