# how to fill array between two points with data from another activity

Tags: java, android

-------UPDATED-------------------------------------

In this class i do the calculations:

```
...
ArrayList<Double> final_cores =new ArrayList<Double>();
...
public void cores_func(){
             double initcores=Double.parseDouble(num_cores.getText().toString().trim());
             double half_time=Double.parseDouble(halftimecores.getText().toString().trim());
             double ttime=Double.parseDouble(timecores.getText().toString().trim());
             double l=Math.log(2)/half_time;
             double fcores=initcores*Math.exp(-l*ttime);
             for (int i=0;i<=ttime;i++){
                  final_cores.add(initcores*Math.exp(-l*ttime));


             }

             //convert ArrayList to double[]

             double[] mydata = new double[final_cores.size()];
             for(int i = 0; i < final_cores.size(); i++) {
                 mydata[i] = final_cores.get(i);
             }
             Intent i=new Intent(this,core_calcs.class);
             i.putExtra("value",fcores);
             i.putExtra("value2",initcores);
             i.putExtra("value3",ttime);
             i.putExtra("final_cores",mydata);
                     startActivity(i);  
         }
          ...
```

and in the linegraph class :

```
...
private double [] final_cores =new double [100];
public double []  getFinal_cores(){ return this.mydata;} 
public void setFinal_cores( double [] final_cores){ this.mydata=mydata;} 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
...
double [] mydata = extras.getDoubleArray("final_cores");
setFinal_cores(mydata);

public Intent getIntent(Context context){
...
 double []mydata=getFinal_cores();

ArrayList<Double> x =new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> y =new ArrayList<Double>();
       // ArrayList<Double> data =new ArrayList<Double>();

         //fill x,y values
         for (int i=0;i<=10;i++){ 
             x.add(ttime / 10.0 * i);
         } 

        for (int i=0;i<=10;i++){ 
         y.add(initcores + ((mydata[i]) / 10.0 * i)); 

     } 


        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Decay");
        for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
            series.add(x.get(i),y.get(i));          
        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what `extras` is?

Comment: @Marvin Pinto:I just use Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();.The user enter in editext the data i am saying.For final_cores i use ArrayList<Double> final_cores =new ArrayList<Double>(); as you can see. (i don't know if i answered your question,forgive me ,am new to java-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Unfortunately for you it does not seem that there is an easy way to pass double ArrayLists. There are two ways you can approach this:

a) You need to create a class that wraps around a double (note: the primitive not the class) and extends Parcelable (guide is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). If this class is called NewDouble, you can use the code below:

```
ArrayList<NewDouble> final_cores = (ArrayList<NewDouble>)extras.getParcelableArrayList("final_cores");
```

b) If you convert the ArrayList to a double[] before putting it in the bundle, you can use getDoubleArray() to a double array.

Quick code to convert an ArrayList to a double array:

```
    double[] doubleArray = new double[final_cores.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < final_cores.size(); i++) {
        doubleArray[i] = final_cores.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: @onit:The above doesn't work.It gives me "cannot cast from parcelable to double".As for 2 and 3 i updated.I hope you understand.Thanks

Comment: Good point. I assumed Double extended Parcelable but it does not.

Comment: :First,thanks for helping.Assume that i create the "doubleArray" (like you did above) ,which holds my data from the other activity.Now,how will i put these data in the y-axis in order to fill it between the initcores-fcores values.

Comment: :Also,what do you mean " ..before putting it in the bundle".Where exactly?And then do "ArrayList<Double> final_cores = (ArrayList<Double>)extras.getDoubleArray("final_cores");" ??

Comment: In your code, when you i.putExtra("final_cores",final_cores);, you are adding data to the bundle. So replace that with i.putExtra("final_cores", doubleArray). So if you convert it to a double array like I said, you can do double[] final_cores = extras.getDoubleArray("final_cores"). To access the value of the array at point i, where 0 < i < ttime/max size of array, you can do final_cores[i]. I still don't understand what you mean by points 2 and 3. Do you understand the difference between an array and an arraylist?

Comment: More info on bundle, you are using this line of code: Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();. When I say bundle, I am talking about this bundle object.

Comment: :Ok,i think we are close!I updated my post.I added comments in some parts,please check.I did the convertion as you said,and i wrote the "double []final_cores..".Now, the "setFinal_cores(final_cores)"doesn't work.What to do with that?And finally i am trying sth like "y.add(final_cores[i])" to fill y ,but i can't figure how to do that.

Comment: I think I've written enough of the code. You need to read up on the difference between an array and and an ArrayList, and a Double object and a double primitive. If you do, you should be able to answer all your questions. If you don't understand these differences, you won't be able to write solid code in the future. There is no point in me just writing all the code for you.

Comment: :First,thanks for your effort.Just ,i am new to java and android,so take it easy.:).I updated my code,i think its ok.One problem only and if its not hard for you to correct me or point me somewhere.The filling i am doing in  is not right (i guess) because the points i am taking all lie on x axis!This is because at y axis instead of showing me "0-initialcores" it shows me only "initialcores".It has no range.Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't trying to sound rude, I just thought that you needed to brush up on your concepts before worrying more about the code. I'm not sure what your asking for with initialcores now.

Comment: :It's ok,i understand.I just have too much things to learn.:).I can't fill right the points for y axis.In my first code above ,i fill as "final_cores.add(initcores*Math.exp(-l*ttime));"and then convert this to "mydata".Then ,i pass mydata to the linegraph class as ".add(initcores + ((mydata[i]) / 10.0 * i)); ".But it doesn't work.It "grabs down" the values of y-axis from "initcores" to infinity instead of "0" to "initcores".

Comment: This is definitely a logic bug and not a programming problem. However, ".add(initcores + ((mydata[i]) / 10.0 * i)); " will always be greater than initcores unless ((mydata[i]) / 10.0 * i)) is < 0. Sorry, but I don't think I can help you here, especially since I don't really know what any of the numbers signify in your algorithm. Also, not to be rude, but I'm not really interested in helping you talk through the math in your algorithm, which is where the problem seems to be.

Comment: :Ok,i had also a fear maybe this was a programming problem.But ok,i will test it.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So to pass the `ArrayList<Double>` from one activity to the other, you have to use the `Parcelable` interface.

You have to create a class called MyDouble for example :

```
public class MyDouble implements Parcelable {
    Double al;


    public MyDouble(Parcel source){
        al = source.readDouble();
    }

    public MyDouble(Double val){
        al = val;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeDouble(al);

    }

    public Double getValueDouble(){
        return this.al;
    }



    public static Parcelable.Creator<MyDouble> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyDouble>() {

        @Override
        public MyDouble createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MyDouble(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MyDouble[] newArray(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new MyDouble[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Instantiate an ArrayList of MyDouble and use :

```
Intent second = new Intent(this, Second.class);
ArrayList<MyDouble>al = new ArrayList<MyDouble>();

MyDouble m1 = new MyDouble(2.0);
MyDouble m2 = new MyDouble(4.0);
al.add(m1);
al.add(m2);
second.putParcelableArrayListExtra("array_list_test", al);
startActivity(second);
```

You retrieve your doubles values, in the other activity by doing :

```
ArrayList<MyDouble> p =b.getParcelableArrayList("array_list_test");
```

I tested it on my machine and it works that way. Hope it helps.

Some documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/

Comment: I added to my post "STEPS" (the last one).I tried to do what you said.I need a little more help on getting the values.Thanks!

Comment: You only want ten values in your arrayList?

Comment: :No.See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954682/how-to-fill-array-list-between-2-points at the answer at the comments please